# How to use a LifoQueue for function calls?

Tags: python, stack, python-3.6

I am making a Sudoku solver and want to make the instructions go one at a time, in a LIFO structure to resemble how most (or at least I) play Sudoku.

The relevant parts of my solver class -

```
class SudokuSolver():
    possible_answers = None

    def __init__(self, board):
        self.board = board
        self.instruction_stack = LifoQueue()
        ...

    def work_on_group(self, group_num):
        print(f"working on group {group_num}")
    
    def work_on_row(self, row):
        print(f"working on row {row}")

    def work_on_column(self, column):
        print(f"working on column {column}")
    
    def do_next_step(self):
        if self.instruction_stack.empty():
            self.instruction_stack.put(self.work_on_group(9))
            self.instruction_stack.put(self.work_on_group(8))
            ...
            self.instruction_stack.put(self.work_on_group(2))
            self.instruction_stack.put(self.work_on_group(1))
        self.instruction_stack.pop()
```

Where eventually my `work_on_group`, `work_on_row` and `work_on_column` functions will have criteria that will add instructions to the stack as results unfold.  However, right now, what I am getting when I try `do_next_step()` is

```
working on group 9
working on group 8
...
working on group 2
working on group 1
```

So it seems like my functions are evaluating as I put them into the stack instead of waiting for me to pop them.

Ideally, what I would see when this runs correctly, is only

`working on group 1`

since that's the last instruction given, and I only have one pop command.

One other thing of note - those these three functions only need one paramter, I can see more complex functions based on the board that would require more parameters, and would like my stack/pop to be able to handle that - store the function reference and then run with with an arbitrary number of `*args **kwargs`.  How can I accomplish this?

Edit:

I've come up with this which works and I think would work fro an arbitrary number of positional parameters, but don't know how I would incorporate keyword argument with this.

```
    def do_next_step(self):
        if self.instruction_stack.empty():
            self.instruction_stack.put((self.work_on_group,(9)))
            self.instruction_stack.put((self.work_on_group,(8)))
            self.instruction_stack.put((self.work_on_group,(7)))
            self.instruction_stack.put((self.work_on_group,(6)))
            self.instruction_stack.put((self.work_on_group,(5)))
            self.instruction_stack.put((self.work_on_group,(4)))
            self.instruction_stack.put((self.work_on_group,(3)))
            self.instruction_stack.put((self.work_on_group,(2)))
            self.instruction_stack.put((self.work_on_group,(1)))
        func, params = self.instruction_stack.get()
        func(params)
```

Comment: It's because you're putting the _result_ of calling the methods into the queue — ie. a `self.instruction_stack.put(self.work_on_group(9))` puts the result of calling `self.work_on_group(9)` into the `instruction_stack`. If you provide a runnable [mre] in your question, so one can show you how to avoid that (if you can't figure it out).

Answer (score 1):

I got this working by changing my `do_next_step` function to the following

```
    def do_next_step(self):
        """
        Creates, and then does, next step into stack.
        """
        if self.instruction_stack.empty():
            self.instruction_stack.put((self.work_on_group,(9,),{}))
            self.instruction_stack.put((self.work_on_group,(8,),{}))
            self.instruction_stack.put((self.work_on_group,(7,),{}))
            self.instruction_stack.put((self.work_on_group,(6,),{}))
            self.instruction_stack.put((self.work_on_group,(5,),{}))
            self.instruction_stack.put((self.work_on_group,(4,),{}))
            self.instruction_stack.put((self.work_on_group,(3,),{}))
            self.instruction_stack.put((self.work_on_group,(2,),{}))
            self.instruction_stack.put((self.work_on_group,(1,),{}))
        func, params, keyword_params = self.instruction_stack.get()
        func(*params, **keyword_params)
```

Comment: Yep, that's the way to do it. This is actually a fairly common way to handle deferred calls (and "callbacks") to functions in Python.